# Build a solution including targets that exist only in a subset of projects in the solution

Tags: sharepoint, msbuild

I have a large solution that consists of 50+ class libraries and ~10 SharePoint WSP projects. I am trying to optimize build times, as by default it takes 5+ minutes on a decent server hardware.

Currently, the build process works like this (pseudocode):

```
MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /T:Clean
MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /T:Build
foreach (Project.csproj in *.csproj where is WSP project)
{
    MSBuild.exe Project.csproj /T:CleanPackage
    MSBuild.exe Project.csproj /T:Package
}
```

What I want to achieve is to do all this using a single `MSBuild.exe` invocation, so that the build process may be parallelized and duplicate processing is avoided when packaging the WSP projects.

I can do this easily for a single WSP project:

```
MSBuild.exe Project.csproj /T:Clean;CleanPackage;Build;Package
```

However, when I do the same for the whole solution:

```
MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /T:Clean;CleanPackage;Build;Package
```

MSBuild fails and reports errors as soon as it finds a project in the solution file that doesn't contain the `CleanPackage` target:

> D:\MySolution\Class.Library.Project\Class.Library.Project.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "CleanPackage" does not exist in the project.

So, the question is, how to overcome this issue and achieve a single-command-line build invocation without a) making manual changes to all `csproj` files (maintenance nightmare), b) writing a custom complicated build script? I was thinking of defining a master build file that would contain a single custom `Target`. However, I'm not sure how to express the right dependencies to projects in the solution file without manually enumerating all the individual projects in two groups (class libraries, WSP projects).

---

*Note: While my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869111/msbuild-ignore-targets-that-dont-exist), I decided to keep it open and self-answer it in order to cover the performance outcomes.*

Comment: Start by speeding up the build (a little) by calling the Rebuild target instead of invoking msbuild twice with Clean/Build, end result is the same. For the other part: should be a fairly simple MSbuild master script, but do the projects with the Package target have to be called in a specific order? Do they depend on each other wrt the Package target or just the Build target?

Comment: @stijn (1) `Rebuild`: minor detail, not exactly the problem I'm solving, and something I already got rid of. (2) No, they are not dependent on each other. A SharePoint WSP package is the end product — something line an `exe`. However, each of them depends on multiple class library projects in the solution.

Comment: @stijn In other words, what I need help with is the “fairly simple MSbuild master script”, as this a tool that I hadn't the need to go much under the hood before.

Comment: Actually just found a duplicate, see first accepted answer, should work for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869111/msbuild-ignore-targets-that-dont-exist. First part is irrelevant I think, but the `MSBuild Solution1.sln /t:Package /p:CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets=...` part should do the trick.

Comment: @stijn I have seen this answer before; however, at first sight, didn't get this might work for my case. Will make a couple tests to verify.

Comment: @stijn So far it seems to work. The outputs of my legacy and updated build process seem equivalent. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Good to hear! Seems the older SO gets, the harder it can become to find the answers here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947427/245183) provides a good way to achieve what I needed. However, the scope of my question is a little bit broader, focused on build performance. Hence this answer includes other findings and outcomes as well.

My supplemental build script looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!-- Enforce "Copy Local = false" on all references -->
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Reference>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <!-- substitute empty CleanPackage and Package targets to each project in case there is no actual implementation -->
  <Target Name="CleanPackage" />
  <Target Name="Package" />
</Project>
```

I also included an override to enforce “Copy Local” to `false`, so that copying of referenced SharePoint assemblies is avoided. This single setting alone **eliminated copying of 3.2 GB (!)** of DLLs and related files to output folders during the build process. I consider this still experimental and needing some fine-tuning, as I expect certain debugging and unit testing scenarios might stop working.

At the end, the single-command-line invocation of `MSBuild` works. An extra parameter is required to pass in a reference to the supplemental build script.

```
MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /T:Clean;CleanPackage;Build;Package  /p:CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets=D:\MySolution\package.targets
```

I was able to cut down build times from 301 seconds down to an average 40.5 seconds, **a 86.5% improvement**. The build sequences I used are:

```
Build sequence without packaging           Avg [sec]  Improvement
----------------------------------------  ----------  --------------
sequential 1xClean, 1xBuild (no package)       124.3
parallel 1xClean, 1xBuild                       58.0  -74.1 (-59.6%)

Build sequence with packaging              Avg [sec]  Improvement
----------------------------------------  ----------  --------------
sequential 1xClean, 1xBuild, NxPackage         301.0  
parallel 1xClean+Build, 1xCleanP+Package       111.0  -190.0 (-63.1%)
parallel 1xClean+Build+CleanP+Package           83.0  -218.0 (-72.4%)
parallel optimized (Copy Local=false)           40.5  -260.5 (-86.5%)
```

Notes:

- `parallel` means the `/m` switch is applied
- `CleanP` is short for `CleanPackage`
- “Copy Local” is `true` except in the fastest build

Hardware: A WS2016 VM with 16 GB RAM, 24 vCPUs running on a dual-Xeon E5-2695 v2 Hyper-V server.